# Efficient way to compare data

Tags: sql, performance, csv

I want to upload a csv file into the database via my php script.

The database contains this numbers

```
part   Description
1      test
2      pc
3      monitor
```

When i upload the csv the code must look if the part already exist in the database, if not he must add him.

for example:

```
my cvs:
1 test
2 pc
4 monitor
5 keyboard
```

if i upload this script he must only add the keyboard.

The database contains 8000 products, how can i compare this efficient and fast?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Upload in temp table the csv file the try an insert select

```
Insert into table as (select  * from temptable minus select * from table)
```